# Is there a way to get transparency from an uploaded video?

Tags: transparency, alpha

https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/102

Is there any way to get transparency from an uploaded video?

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Open Player scene
- Log in using auth token
- Choose a video stream that contains alpha (using a color code)
- Hit play and confirm the stream playing with the color code
- How can I swap this color code out for alpha? Is there perhaps another way to handle alpha?

Answer (score 0):

could you specific the data format of "color code"?
Does it just a float between 0-1, or 0-255?

In general, if you have any data format in pixel[] or texture2D, you can customise a simple shader with transparent pass support.